# Session variable not working how I expected, what am I doing wrong

Tags: php, session-variables

so I have a page that has products on it and when you run a job on one of the products it needs to display the name of the job that is running beside the product.

I was hoping to basically check an array using the product id and see if there is a job that exists for it.

so when you click a button for a job it goes to the process page which does this

```
$_SESSION['jobInfo'] = array();
$_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId] = array ( name => $jobName, id => $vAppId);
```

then on the front page it has

```
if ($curActiveJobName = $_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId]['name'] != ""){

    $curActiveJobName = $_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId]['name'];
    $curActiveJobId = $_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId]['id'];

}
```

and then I use the $curActiveJobName and $curActiveJobId further down in my code for display.

Now the problem I am having is that it only seems to work the first time and then only for that product. It seems like when I try to run a job on a second product it doesn't make the session variable.  Any help is really appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are you calling session_start() on both pages or atleast in the bootstrapping code?

Comment: yes I am, thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You need one more depth -

```
$_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId][] = array ( name => $jobName, id => $vAppId);
```

And the checks will be -

```
$cur_entry = end($_SESSION['jobInfo'][$vAppId]);
if ($curActiveJobName = $cur_entry['name'] != ""){ // Add empty() check if needed

    $curActiveJobName = $cur_entry['name'];
    $curActiveJobId = $cur_entry['id'];

}
```